# Люди, сдающие в аренду вещи

Tags: лексика

Как называют людей, дающих вещи напрокат?

Answer (score 2):

Таких людей называют ***Арендодатель***.

Answer (score 0):

**Арендодатель** носит официальный оттенок.

Про человека, сдающего в аренду квартиру, в разговорной речи скорее скажут **хозяин (хозяйка)** или - этот вариант мне кажется устаревшим - **квартирный хозяин (квартирная хозяйка)**.

Но в вопросе упоминалась аренда *вещей*.

Человека, занимающегося прокатом свадебных платьев, могут назвать **прокатчик**.